# Is it acceptable to start a sentence with an adverb of frequency?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence-starts

Daily the company sells millions of chocolate bars.

The sentence sounds really odd to me but is it wrong?

Comment: Often these questions are hard to answer.

Comment: Why do you think not? Have consulted any sources on grammar? Let us know to help you better.

Comment: It's stylized, and draws attention, but that may be the purpose. After all, this is text about commerce and therefore is advertising.

Answer (score 1):

It's not wrong to start the sentence with an adverb of time or frequency, especially if the time or frequency of the action is essential for the writer or speaker.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! It is generally viewed to be good practice to add sources and use citations to base your answer upon. Examples in a case such as this would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

"Daily I fall in love with waitresses" https://writersalmanac.publicradio.org/index.php%3Fdate=2011%252F01%252F18.html

Answer (score 0):

Many people do.
Oft has a brother most sincerely gone.
Once more onto the beach dear friends.